# Making sure http appears in a web address

Tags: php, http, hyperlink, href

I have people posting their website address but variations are posted such as:

- theirsite.com
- www.theirsite.com
- http://theirsite.com
- http://www.theirsite.com

When I link to an address without http:// it takes the link as internal

```
<a href="theirsite.com">their site</a>
```

sending people to something like: http://mysite.com/thiersite.com

Another option I've tried is linking to something like mysite.com/?link=theirsite.com - This way I can do some link tracking etc then redirect people to the link but it has the same problem:

```
//do some tracking etc here
$link =$_GET['link'];
header("Location: $link");
```

Comment: Tell us what language your using, and we can help you with the code.

Comment: This is so PHP-style tagged. There is no need to tag this question as http. It's abusive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to use regular expressions here. PHP has URL validation built in.

[Filter Var](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php)

```
var_dump((bool) filter_var('http://www.website.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
var_dump((bool) filter_var('http://website.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
var_dump((bool) filter_var('www.website.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
var_dump((bool) filter_var('website.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED));
```

Output

```
bool(true)
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Please do not jump straight to regular expressions for validation, PHP has a lot of methods built in to deal with these scenarios.

-Mathew

Comment: But regular expressions are language independent.

Comment: To be fair, he posted it with a PHP tag and I've given him a PHP answer. It's a non-issue.

Answer (score 2):

put "http://" in the field by default, then validate the URL with something like

```
if(eregi("^((http|https)://)?([[:alnum:]-])+(\.)([[:alnum:]]){2,4}([[:alnum:]/+=%&_.~?-]*)$", stripslashes(trim($_POST['link'])))){
    //link is valid
}
```

if link does not validate, just print them a message saying "the link you entered is invalid, make sure it starts with 'http://'"

Comment: I like how this will also take care of the cases when people write "no" or "not yet" or stuff like that.

Comment: +1 For the default value for the URL field. But I wouldn’t use `eregi`.

Comment: No need to use regular expressions in this case. PHP has built in URL validation using the "filter" extension. See my answer below.

Comment: ereg is dead, you should use PCRE instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like this:

```
$link = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', trim($link));
if (!preg_match('/^https?:\/\//', $link)) {
    $link = 'http://'.$link;
}
header('Location: '.$link);
```

Another way would be the [`parse_url` function](http://docs.php.net/parse_url) to parse the given URL, see what parts are missing and add them.

Comment: might need to consider trailing space as noted by Elazar and also there was a small typo repalce. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Please note, there's a real difference between `www.site.com` and `site.com`, usually both works, but on some website each leads to a different path (some badly defined website won't work without the `www` for instance). So You can't always prepend 'www' to the input.

Another note, do handle prepending space, so that `' http://'` would not be prepended with additional `http://`.

My Javascript Regex based solution

```
'http://'+field.replace(/^ *http:\/\//,'')
```

You can verify that on the client size, just put a code in similar spirit on the `onSubmit` of your form.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide some validation or sanitation. Use a regex to see if http:// starts with it. If it doesn't, either throw an validation error or put http:// at the start.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not "://" in users_url:
    users_url = "http://" + users_url
```

...or equivalent, in the language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expressions to test input

```
Regex exp = new Regex(
    @"http://(www\.)?([^\.]+)\.com",
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Hopefully the .com is just an example :D